# Gain or amplification

Tags: circuit-design

I need to amplify a 5 to 50 mV signal to 0.3 to 2 Volts over 20hz to 40k. Or at least that's the range I'm concerned with. What about an op-amp spec tells me if it can do this? Can you please provide an example of a suitable and unsuitable spec sheet
What are the equations used to calculate my needed gain?

Comment: Gain is \$A_v = \frac{2 - 0.3}{0.05 - 0.005}\$.  To know if a given op-amp can do it, you also need to know the maximum frequency of interest in your signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For voltage op amps (the usual kind) you need to do 3 things. First, find the maximum gain you need. Second, multiply this times the greatest frequency you need, and then multiply this by at least 10. This is called the gain-bandwidth product. Finally, multiply peak voltage times the highest frequency times 2 pi. This is the required slew rate.

Now check that your gain-bandwidth product is less than the op amp gain bandwidth. The reason for the added factor of 10 (or more) is because the op amp needs what's called excess gain in order to provide accurate signal amplification. If the op amp's GBW is OK, check the slew rate requirement against the op amp slew rate.

Finally, you have not specified the load which the op amp must drive. If this is something benign, like an amplifier you should have no trouble. On the other hand, if you're trying to drive a load such as a speaker, you may need to learn about amplifier loading.

Answer (score 0):

the gain required is about 2000/50= 40. try using an op amp such as LF353 with gain bandwidth product of more than 40*40khz= 1.6 MHz. LF 353 has a gain bandwidth product of 4 MHz.